# Visits on a page not incrementing python google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, jinja2

I am trying to check for the number of visits on a page using this code.
My browser is firefox v 39.
Somehow the count is not getting incremented.
Can some one let me know what the issue is in here ?

```
        import os
        import webapp2
        import jinja2
        import re
        from google.appengine.ext import db
        from functions import check_secure_val,make_secure_val

        temp_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates')
        jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(temp_dir), autoescape = True)

        class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
            def write(self,*a,**az):
                self.response.write(*a,**az)
            def render_template(self,template,**params):
                t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
                return t.render(params)
            def render_page(self, template, **az):
                self.write(self.render_template(template,**az))

        class MainHandler(Handler):
                def get(self):
                        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
                        visits = 0
                        visit_cookie_str = self.request.cookies.get('visits')
                        if visit_cookie_str:
                                cookie_val = check_secure_val(visit_cookie_str)
                                if cookie_val:
                                        visits = int(cookie_val)

                        visits += 1

                        new_cookie_val = make_secure_val(str(visits))

                        self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'visits=%s' % new_cookie_val)

                        if visits > 100:
                                self.write("You are the best ever!")
                        else:
                                self.write("You've been here %s times!" % visits)






        app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set cookies by adding a header, rather than using the [available methods](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#setting-cookies)?

Comment: I am a newbie who is trying to get to terms with web development. Do you have an example that i could look at ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code visits is a local variable. It will not be reused across requests. Regardless this is not the best way keep counter. AppEngine will shard your application across multiple machines and will move it once in a while. You need to use datastore, memcached or some other way of persistent storage to implement page view count correctly. Also keep in mind that you need your page to disable browser cache.

Comment: Thank you Vlad, do you have a suggestion as to how i can use the counter in a better way? Do you have a code example ?